# Can Windows Phone 7.0 apps still be uploaded to the Windows Store?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Can Windows Phone 7.0 apps still be uploaded to the Windows Store or do they have to be updated to Windows Phone 7.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, its still supported i think. refer this link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184840%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

it suggests 7.0 app can be submitted.

[image]